# Cruise Control and Powershell

Tags: powershell, cruisecontrol

this is my first time i am using Cruise Control, so maybe i did not understand it properly. I want to start a large PowerShell script, that builds some VM Images. And it would be really cool, if i could have a look at it via cruise control.
I allready googled the stuff and i found stuff like this: http://qaquestions.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/cruisecontrol-net-powershell-tasks/
but now:
Where exactly do i put these xml statements? I thought, i had to create a new project tag in CC config.xml and specify the script and location. But when i start the queue it says, that powershell is a unknown plugin, but i have CC 2.5+ and PS should be supported since 1.5. 
I am just not quite sure, what to do :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the absolute minimum project definition necessary to run a powershell task in Cruise Control .NET. I would assume it is probably fairly similiar in Cruise Control.

```
<project name="Run some powershell scripts">
    <tasks>
        <powershell>
            <scriptsDirectory>path to scripts folder</scriptsDirectory>
            <script>script to run</script>
        </powershell>
    </tasks>
</project>
```

Place this project definition in your config file (ccnet.config for Cruise Control .NET)

Comment: OK, since i could not find the powershell option for cruise-control, i will use cruisecontrol.net. When i insert your codesnippet, the project is being started (starting integratos for project: powershellTest), but then it stucks and the script is not executed...
What have i done wrong?

Comment: OK, the script works now. But the dashboard does not work :/ As i understood it, the dashboard is allready included in the basic Installation, right? And i should reach the dashboard via localhost\ccnet. But my browser always says, that the page can not be displayed :/ Did i forget to install something?

Comment: You need to create the Virtual Directory in IIS (or your web server of choice). It will need to point to the webdashboard folder in your install directory. It should just work out of the box, but you may need to do a little configuration depending on your specific setup

Answer (score 0):

There are some more articles in blog you mentioned http://qaquestions.wordpress.com/category/ci/cruise-control-net-ci/ For overall reference use documentation http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html